# Why do speakers synchronize with mouse/scrolling/other OS actions?

Tags: hardware-failure, speakers

Whenever I move my mouse, my speakers emit a very tiny but audible high pitched noise; whenever I scroll they emit a lower frequency noise; overall in all my custom builds, unless the speaker is disabled it always plays sounds relating to software actions; is this normal? how should I fix it?

Comment: Reminds me of http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Coffee-Beats-Wireless.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This in not actually a sound that is played through the sound card. This is a kind of E.M.I. (Electromagnetic Interference). This is caused by a bad motherboard circuit design. Actually the signal needed for the speakers in order to become audible is very small (~50mV Effective). So every small interference is audible. The high pitch noise is nothing more than a harmonic of the USB Communication frequency which is too high to get audible.

To solve this you have to experiment some alternatives:

- Change ports/audio jacks, avoiding the front panel
- Ensure your earth circuit is working properly

P.S:checking the earth circuitry closely requires special equipment and training. If you don't meet these conditions, do not try to disassemble and inspect anything related to mains power supply. This could prove fatal if you don't have the necessary training and knowledge!

Comment: Of course, the definitive solution is to have a dedicated sound card.
Amplifying the system sound and reducing the speakers volume may also help reducing the interference noise heard. (or not)

Comment: Sometimes this works, sometimes not. It's all about ground loops, interference, electromagnetism, and it's out of regular computer user knowledge. It's an electronic circuit problem. The sound card you mentioned earlier could also amplify even the noise, thus creating a mess. A quick workaround is to forget about front panel USB and install a dedicated header in a 3.5" bay or 5.25" one. Remember, the far the noise source is relative to the useful signal(in our case audio), the smaller the audible noise will be.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me as well when I plugged both my earphones and a disk-on-key in the front panel.
As far as I understand it happens due to some bad design of the circuit board.

What you can do is just plug at least one of them to the main board (worked for me).